# Bash script works on ssh but not in php

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian

i have a bash script (myscript.sh) and this works at the ssh console with the user "www-data" but when i run this script with "exec" in my php script then the script does not work.

Whats the problem? "www-data" has the shell "/bin/bash" and when i set to "/bin/sh" then the script does not work, too.

Comment: You must be referencing the environment of logged in user. Also, make sure all paths used in the script are absolute. Without seeing the script, it is rather difficult to guess what could go wrong.

Comment: Where is you bash script relative to your php file?

Answer (score 0):

Take care of executable mode

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

and if script is in path. Otherwise use full path when calling myscript.sh

Comment: I have check this but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an 'insecure' way of doing this, I had a similar problem once, you could change all the permissions on your file also - at the command line type:

First make a copy of your original file - just in case, so we don't mess it up further:

```
    cp myscript.sh myscript2.sh

    chmod 755 myscript2.sh
```

and at the command line type:

```
    chown www-data:www-data myscript2.sh
```

Have a try with myscript2 in the PHP script file instead. ( I remember also identifying the problem similar to this to have some relation to running the web server(I’m assuming you use Apache) as root.)

By the way OP, have you looked at your error logs? there may be a useful suggestion as to what is being disallowed.

Comment: Why would you set the permissions to `777`? What's wrong with `755`?

Comment: I just typed and didn't think, perhaps I should change, I think you mean that the OP only really needs to give 'user' access 'rwx' and g-rx, o-rx, permission, by that comment?

Comment: Right. There's no point (and, depending on the system, considerable danger) in giving write access to anyone but the owner. (I could have been clearer about that.)